# Setting the Value to an Object by using Void or return type approach

Tags: java

I have `Employee` class and I am trying to set a value to employee `name` property:

```
public class Employee {
private String name;
private String id;
// setters and getters
}
```

I have got two options: by using `void` or using a return type.

```
public class EmpClient {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        EmpClient emp_client = new EmpClient();
        emp_client.setNameToEmployee(emp);
        System.out.println(emp.getName());
    
    }
    
    public void setNameUsingVoid(Employee emp) {
        emp.setName("Mark");
    }
    
    public Employee setNameToEmployee(Employee emp) {
        emp.setName("Taylor");
    
        return emp;
    }
}
```

This is my code and through both the approaches, it works.
Please let me know what is the preferred and more **efficient** way? What are the pros and cons of using each of the methods, and under what circumstances should they be used?

Comment: For this situation the first one is better. In the second one you return a reference to the `emp` object to which you already have a reference which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: There's no correct way. But in some situations you may want to take the second approach a bit further: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Comment: its totally useless. not recommendable . why you want this type of approach? why because if u set name then others field will be null. so why that much effort to set a single value.

Comment: Both works fine but the idea is: what is the purpose of returning a result? The purpose of setters is to set the value for the instance object and that is it. so returning a the employee back is unnecessary, returning anything is unnecessary in most cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want the method to do. For most cases `setNameUsingVoid()` method would be suitable. You want to assign a name to the employee and this method achieves that.
When instead you have this statement in your main method.

```
setNameToEmployee(emp);
```

The desired assignment is done and additionally,  a reference is also returned. Here you are not using the returned value, so it is just unnecessary extra work. So if you are going to use the statement in the above fashion, use setNameUsingVoid() instead.
Note: According to the Java Language Specification, the above statement is a valid statement though the returned value is not being used. [For more info on the validity of such statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763209/why-i-am-able-to-call-a-non-void-functions-without-using-the-returned-values-in)
If instead you were to use `setNameToEmployee()` in this way:

```
Employee e1 = setNameToEmployee(emp);
```

You should opt for using this function over the other one. However in this specific use case the statement makes no sense at all because you are idly making a second copy of your `Employee` object. Summing up:
**In this case (or any case where you pass a reference at return the same thing), it is best to use `setNameUsingVoid()`, as it is very difficult to think of a case where `setNameToEmployee()` might actually be beneficial.**